# Android get the value null when passing from fragment to dialogfragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

i have a question i using bundle to send data from fragment to dialogfragment, but there is a problem when i click on the button in my fragment layout it success to get the data from fragment but in my dialogfragment it get the null value , when i debug i found that my dialog fragment run two time so that why i get the null value. Any suggestion to solve this problem, sorry for my english, hope can understand my question.

This is my onclick to pass data to my dialog fragment

```
 Button[i].setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
 Button[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                               TextView test = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.testproductname);
                                test.setText(pName);
                                String testproductname = test.getText().toString();

                                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                                args.putString("key", testproductname);
                                FragmentDialog newFragment = new FragmentDialog();
                                newFragment.setArguments(args);
                                newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "TAG");

                                showTheDialog();
                     }
             });
 }
protected void showTheDialog() {
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentDialog overlay = new FragmentDialog();
    overlay.show(fm, "FragmentDialog");

 }
```

**FragmentDialog**

```
   public class FragmentDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW));
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle
            savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.prompt_quantity, container);

        // tab slider
        sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.modifierpager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);

        Bundle mArgs = getArguments();
        pName = mArgs.getString("key","asdasd");

        final TextView tpn = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.gtestproductname);
        tpn.setText(pName);
}
```

Comment: what is `showTheDialog()`? it seems you're already calling `newFragment.show` before it...

Comment: thanks, i update my question, showThDialog() is use to prompt up my dialogfragment

Comment: if you are calling the dialog fragment from `showTheDialog()` it will show it again with null values and you are calling to show the dialog in the previous line `newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "TAG"); //here you are calling to show the fragment`


and `showTheDialog(); //Are you showing the fragment again here?`

Comment: showing 2 dialogs at a time?

Comment: try to comment out the `showTheDialog` function call, and see if it solves the issue

Comment: @marmor thanks, problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "TAG");

                            showTheDialog();
```

you need not call show twice, this logic draws the view twice. That is why you have the anomaly. Remove the second one.